# Hibernate Search never stops indexing

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

If I mark more than one entity as @Indexed, Hibernate search never stops the indexing of these entities. Futhermore the tables of these entities are empty. Everything works fine, when only one entity is marked with @Indexed.

The entities are realy simple and have a structure like this (written in Scala)

```
@Indexed(index="index/some_entity")
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_entity")
class SomeEntity extends BaseIdEntity {

  @Transient
  val nameLength: Int = 50
  @Column(length = 50)
  @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
  @BeanProperty var name: String = _

  ....
}
```

In the debug-mode I could see that the Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager).createIndexer().startAndWait() will be correct left, but after this I can see "BatchIndexingWorkspace"-Threads, one thread for each entity(@Indexed), which will be never finalized.

I tried it with different Hibernate Search version between 4.3 and 5.0.1

Any ideas or suggestions?? I have no ideas any more.

Comment: I think you should enable HibernateSearch API log, it seems some error is coming inside the API itself. (i.e some initialization related stuff)

Comment: Are you using embedded indexing? Then you could have some endless loop?! Can you provide the full code example with all indexed classes and fields?

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for my late reply. Until a few days before I couldn't spent time for this problem, but it's fixed now. See my answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that the indexer was initlized two times in two different beans. The second call of Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager).createIndexer().startAndWait() never returned. I just removed the needless call and it works now :)